# which version of ojdbc jar for JDK6 and oracle dB 12.2 use?

Tags: jar, ojdbc

I am tried to connect **Oracle 12.2.0** with **Ojdbc6.jar**.

I installed j**dk 6.13** but not able to login to database.

I getting this exception:`ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.

I am 100% sure my username and password is correct as I am able to login from **Oracle TOAD** using these same credentials.

My username and password contains an underscore(`_`) character.